# Apache Camel ResolveEndpointFailedException - Failed to resolve endpoint

Tags: jboss, apache-camel, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I was trying to access an outside service built in ASP.net using Jboss fuse and Camel. I am new to this integration thing using Fuse. When I try to run the following camel-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
    JBoss, Home of Professional Open Source
    Copyright 2014, Red Hat, Inc. and/or its affiliates, and individual
    contributors by the @authors tag. See the copyright.txt in the
    distribution for a full listing of individual contributors.

    Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    You may obtain a copy of the License at
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    limitations under the License.
-->
<!-- Configures the Camel Context-->
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd        http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd    ">
    <cxf:cxfEndpoint address="/report" id="reportEndpoint" serviceClass="com.mycompany.camel.cxf.code.first.spring.incident.IncidentService"/>
    <cxf:cxfEndpoint
        address="http://www.webservicex.net/CurrencyConvertor.asmx"
        endpointName="c:SOAPOverHTTP" id="wsdlEndpoint"
        serviceName="c:CurrencyConvertor" xmlns:s="http://www.webserviceX.NET"/>
    <bean
        class="com.mycompany.camel.cxf.code.first.spring.incident.ReportIncidentProcessor" id="reportIncidentProcessor"/>
    <bean
        class="com.mycompany.camel.cxf.code.first.spring.incident.StatusIncidentProcessor" id="statusIncidentProcessor"/>
    <camelContext id="camelContext-c1100b64-c8cb-4fa6-b382-5eea0e303c95" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <route id="asmx_route1">
            <from id="_from1" uri="file:src/data/auth?noop=true"/>
            <log id="_log1" message="${body}"/>
            <to id="_to3" uri="cxf:bean:wsdlEndpoint?dataFormat=MESSAGE"/>
            <log id="_log2" message="${body}"/>
        </route>
        <route id="cxf">
            <!--  route starts from the cxf webservice in POJO mode -->
            <from id="reportEndpointListener" uri="cxf:bean:reportEndpoint"/>
            <recipientList id="dispatchToCorrectRoute">
                <simple>direct:${header.operationName}</simple>
            </recipientList>
        </route>
        <route id="report">
            <from id="reportIncidentStarter" uri="direct:reportIncident"/>
            <log id="logReportIncident" message="reportIncident Call"/>
            <process id="reportIncidentProcess" ref="reportIncidentProcessor"/>
            <to id="_to1" uri="log:output"/>
        </route>
        <route id="status">
            <from id="statusIncidentStarter" uri="direct:statusIncident"/>
            <log id="logStatusIncident" message="statusIncident Call"/>
            <process id="statusIncidentProcess" ref="statusIncidentProcessor"/>
            <to id="_to2" uri="log:output"/>
        </route>
    </camelContext>
</beans>
```

I get this error in the fuse log,

```
org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: direct: due to: Expected scheme-specific part at index 7: direct:
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.normalizeEndpointUri(DefaultCamelContext.java:661)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.getEndpoint(DefaultCamelContext.java:543)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.util.CamelContextHelper.getMandatoryEndpoint(CamelContextHelper.java:79)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.util.ExchangeHelper.resolveEndpoint(ExchangeHelper.java:89)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientListProcessor.resolveEndpoint(RecipientListProcessor.java:254)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientListProcessor.createProcessorExchangePairs(RecipientListProcessor.java:193)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MulticastProcessor.process(MulticastProcessor.java:231)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.sendToRecipientList(RecipientList.java:170)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RecipientList.process(RecipientList.java:131)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:121)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:83)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:77)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:468)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:196)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$CxfConsumerInvoker.asyncInvoke(CxfConsumer.java:154)[241:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfConsumer$CxfConsumerInvoker.invoke(CxfConsumer.java:133)[241:org.apache.camel.camel-cxf:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:59)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.5.redhat-630187]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_121]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$2.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:126)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.5.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.SynchronousExecutor.execute(SynchronousExecutor.java:37)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.5.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:131)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.5.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.5.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)[74:org.apache.cxf.cxf-core:3.1.5.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:254)[118:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.5.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234)[118:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.5.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208)[118:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.5.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160)[118:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.5.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:180)[118:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.5.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:299)[118:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.5.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doGet(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:223)[118:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.5.redhat-630187]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)[81:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:274)[118:org.apache.cxf.cxf-rt-transports-http:3.1.5.redhat-630187]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:812)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.doHandle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:71)[117:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)[93:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)[92:org.eclipse.jetty.security:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)[93:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)[93:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.doHandle(HttpServiceContext.java:287)[117:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)[94:org.eclipse.jetty.servlet:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)[93:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)[93:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)[93:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:80)[117:org.ops4j.pax.web.pax-web-jetty:4.3.0]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)[93:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)[93:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)[93:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)[93:org.eclipse.jetty.server:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)[86:org.eclipse.jetty.io:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)[96:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)[96:org.eclipse.jetty.util:9.2.19.v20160908]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_121]
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected scheme-specific part at index 7: direct:
    at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.failExpecting(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_121]
    at java.net.URI.<init>(Unknown Source)[:1.8.0_121]
    at org.apache.camel.util.URISupport.normalizeUri(URISupport.java:534)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext.normalizeEndpointUri(DefaultCamelContext.java:659)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630187]
    ... 54 more
```

Please ask if you need anymore sources I used so that I can give you a clear understanding. Thanks in advance.

Comment: makr sure `${header.operationName}` is not null or empty or evaluated correctly

Comment: As I am new to this platform, I do not have much understanding with these evaluation or checking. can you please provide an example.

Comment: Probably the request arriving on `/report` is not a SOAP POST. Maybe a GET reading the WSDL?

Comment: The exception URISyntaxException is pointing to some malformed URI, it seems that it is a issue due to /report being set as address on the reportEndpoint. Check if it runs fine by commenting out the reportEndpoint.